# Insert jQuery input into a table template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with something, I have a table template into a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var myTab= "<table id='mag-1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>"+libellesMag['nom']+"</td></tr></table>";
```

Where `libellesMag['nom']` is a jQuery variable which contains an input type text.

When I `append()` this variable my input is displayed but when I try to concatenate my variable in a string and `append()` this string my `libellesMag['nom']` display `[Object object]`

Do you have any idea how to display my input?

EDIT: `console.log(libellesMag['nom'])=[input#monapp_homebundle_enseignetype_magasins_1_nomMagasin, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: div, selector: ":nth-child(2)", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add your element to a parent to then use [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the parent, you can create a temporary element to use as a parent, so to not affect the DOM of your page, do it like this:

```
var myTab= "<table id='mag-1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>" + $('<span>').append(libellesMag['nom']).html() + "</td></tr></table>";
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/5d039)

Note the span element I used is never added to your DOM it's only used as a temporary parent for your element, so we can use `.html()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `libellesMag['nom'].val()`, like this:

```
var myTab= "<table id='mag-1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>"+libellesMag['nom'].val()+"</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: like the previous comment i tried like this too but nothing is displayed even in the console.. but thanks ;)

Comment: Are you sure the input field contains any value? What does `console.log(libellesMag['nom'].val())` output? Undefined?

Comment: it displays nothing but when i explore the node (with console.log(libellesMag['nom'])) from the console i have my input in an attribute outerHTML:"<input type="text" id="magasins_1_nom" name="magasin[magasins][1][adresse]" >"